# How does Hive decide when to use map reduce and when not to?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive

As a simple example,

```
select * from tablename;
```

DOES NOT kick in map reduce, while

```
select count(*) from tablename;
```

DOES. What is the general principle used to decide when to use map reduce (by hive)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In general, any sort of aggregation, such as min/max/count is going to require a MapReduce job. This isn't going to explain everything for you, probably.

Hive, in the style of many RDBMS, has an [`EXPLAIN`](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Explain) keyword that will outline how your Hive query gets translated into MapReduce jobs. Try running explain on both your example queries and see what it is trying to do behind the scenes.

Answer (score 6):

Whenever we fire a query like **select * from *tablename***, Hive reads the data file and fetches the entire data without doing any aggregation(min/max/count etc.). It'll call a **FetchTask** rather than a **mapreduce** task.

This is also an optimization technique in Hive. **hive.fetch.task.conversion** property can (i.e. FETCH task) minimize latency of map-reduce overhead.

This is like we are reading a hadoop file : ***hadoop fs -cat filename***

But if we use **select colNames from tablename**, it requires a map-reduce job as it needs to extract the 'column' from each row by parsing it from the file it loads.

Comment: With newer versions of hive, the second part isn't true anymore..`select column from tablename` won't run an MR with `minimal` or `more` setting of `hive.fetch.task.conversion`

Answer (score 1):

> select * from tablename;

Just reads raw data from files in HDFS, so it is much faster without MapReduce.

Comment: but for a large file it has to read from all the nodes in parallel. Hive does that without MR?

Answer (score -1):

It is an optimisation technique, `hive.fetch.task.conversion` property can (FETCH) task minimize latency of mapreduce overhead.

When doing SELECT, LIMIT, FETCH queries this property skips mapreduce and uses the FETCH task.

This property can have 3 values - `none`, `minimal` (the default) and `more`.