# Hive Map reduce Job clarification on selecting column

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive

Map reduce Jobs on Hive Statement

When i Query the following statment in Hive

```
hive>  SELECT * FROM USERS LIMIT 100;
```

**It doesn't launch a Map reduce Job**, as becuase we are selection every things from the table and limiting the number of records it's return

But when i do the following

```
hive> select age,occupation from users limit 100;
```

***it's actually kicks a Map reduce Job ?***

does that means, applying column level projection required a Map reduce Job, ? though i have not applied any kind of filter on it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does Hive decide when to use map reduce and when not to?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7466454/how-does-hive-decide-when-to-use-map-reduce-and-when-not-to)

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you run a normal 'select *', a fetch task is created rather than a mapreduce task which just dumps the data as it is without doing anything on it. This is equivalent to a:

```
hadoop fs -cat $file_name
```

Whereas whenever you do a 'select column', a map job internally filters that particular column and gives the output.

Answer (score 0):

when you write `select * from table_name`, the whole file is viewed, while if you select column, a map only job is launched, no reduce will be launched for it, since we are selecting the whole column .

```
Select * from table_name; -->  will not launch a MR JOB 
Select column from table_name; -->  will launch a M JOB (map only job)
```

`Select MAX(column_name) from table_name;` -->  will launch a MR JOB