# One query runs map reduce, the other does not

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have a table inside hive, I want to fetch all data from it. The problem is that:

```
select * from tbl;
```

Gives me very different results than:

```
select count(*) from tbl;
```

Why is that? The second query seems to be running hadoop map reduce, the first does not - it simply returns the results. The table is not partitioned or bucketed, it's in the text (csv) format.

Comment: There is the same question as yours: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7466454/how-does-hive-decide-when-to-use-map-reduce-and-when-not-to And there is accepted answer exists.

Answer (score 0):

When you submit a Hive query, Hive converts a query into one or more stages. Stages could be a MapReduce stage, a sampling stage, a merge stage, a limit stage, or other possible tasks Hive needs to do.

`select * from table_name;`

This query simply scan the entire table and dump the output on screen, therefore you see the different log output on console.

While `select count(*) from table_name` just scan the Hive meta_information and put the result from their itself. It also don't run any MapReduce job.

You can run below command on Hive console and you will be able to see the entire information.

`hive> describe formatted table_name`;

Table Parameters:

```
COLUMN_STATS_ACCURATE   true
numFiles                xx
numRows                 xxxxxxxx
```

In hadoop, aggregation/conditional/arithmetical operations etc required a processing engine to process and execute the result and therefore whenever you submit this type of job, it internally get translated into a MapReduce program, the MapReduce program gets executed on behalf of the query and produce its result to hive and Hive display on your screen and therefore you see a different result.

You can put the `EXPLAIN` keyword in front of the query to see the query plan and other information.

Please refer Programming Hadoop Book, Chapter 10 to know more about use of Hive `EXPLAIN` features.