# Hive getting stuck for queries, what can be the issue?

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop, hive, hadoop-yarn

I have installed Hive and it executes basic queries properly, but is getting stuck for queries like distinct. On going to the link for checking the problem it displays

> ACCEPTED: waiting for AM container to be allocated, launched and register with RM.

as the YarnApplicationStage.

I have tried making changes in the yarn-site.xml by increasing the percentage of YARN scheduler capacity too. But nothing is working. It still seems to be stuck at the same step. I have attached the yarn-site.xml code, Application screenshot and also the hive screenshot. Also there are no unhealthy nodes and the screenshot of the same has been attached.

```
<property>
<name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
<value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>mapreduce.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce_shuffle.class</name>
<value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>yarn.resourcemanager.address</name>
<value>127.0.0.1:8032</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.maximum-am-resource-percent</name>
<value>1.0</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb</name>
<value>4096</value>
<description>Physical memory, in MB, to be made available to running containers</description>
</property>   
</configuration>
```

The error image as the following order,

**Hive stuck error**

**Application Manager**

**Nodes details**

**Yarn Node Manager Log**
[image: hive stuck error]

[image: Application manager]

[image: Nodes details]

[[image: Yarn Nodemanager Log][4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BrOUN.jpg)
[[image: Yarn Node Manager Log][5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o6RhQ.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your cluster metrics show you have no vcores, no memory and no active nodes so that means you cannot do any processing until you add a Node Manager to your cluster.

The Resource Manager is the scheduler but the Node Managers provide the compute resources.

The reason you see this when doing a DISTINCT is that Hive can process some queries without triggering a MapReduce job.

#### References

- [YARN Architecture](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.8.0/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/YARN.html)
- [How does Hive decide when to use map reduce and when not to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7466454/how-does-hive-decide-when-to-use-map-reduce-and-when-not-to)

Comment: So how can I add the Node Manager?

Comment: How are you running your cluster?

Comment: What? Which file should I check for looking at the clusters?

Comment: Is this a single node or are you using more than one machine for Hadoop and Hive?

Comment: Just one machine.

Comment: Did you follow https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.8.0/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html#YARN_on_a_Single_Node?

Comment: Yes, I have followed these steps.

Comment: Look at the YARN logs to see why you don't have a Node Manager running.

Comment: I checked. I have attached the log ending to the post,

Comment: There is not enough information in the log to determine the problem.  Also, you should have a Node Manager log.

Comment: The above image is the node manager log. The last statement of the log is INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeStatusUpdaterImpl: Notifying ContainerManager to unblock new container-requests.

Comment: What does the RM log show?  If your NM is connected you should have resources to at least launch your AM.  Also what does the RM UI show?

Comment: I have attached a new log file which shows that it gets stuck when it is trying to register wit RM

Comment: So, you have a Node Manager but no resources to do any compute.  Can you confirm this through the RM UI?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this error. The problem was with the etc/hosts file. The IP of my system had changed due to which hive was not running properly.